# Accumulating jQuery html elements to add to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build html elements using jQuery but I'm having trouble figuring out how to map over a dataset, build all the html elements (how to store?) then append the entire thing in one shot?

```
buildHeader: () => {
    var $headerHtml = $();

    fields.map(f => {
        var $element = $("<td>", { class: "frb-das-header", text: f.title });
        $headerHtml = $headerHtml.append($element);
    });
    return $headerHtml.html();
},
```

I'm calling it using a template string `<tr>${this.buildHeader()}</tr>` but I don't get anything back

Use case: I have a table and I want to render all the headers or table rows by iterating over array, building the html, then rendering that out.

EDIT: Can get it to render but it deleted the `<tr>` I set initially.

```
buildHeader: () => {
    var $headerHtml = $("<tr>", {
        class: "frb-das-headers"
    });

    frb.config.lizsts.das.tableFields.map(f => {
        $headerHtml.append(
            $("<td>", {
                class: "frb-das-header",
                text: f
            })
        );
    });
    return $headerHtml.html();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

`$()` is an empty jQuery object and the purpose of `append()` is to insert the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection.

So you cannot `append()` `$element` to `$headerHtml`.

```js
let fields = [
  {title: "H1"},
  {title: "H2"},
  {title: "H3"},
]

let buildHeader = function () {
  // initial a <tr> element
  var $headerHtml = $("<tr>");
  fields.map(f => {
    var $element = $("<td>", {
      class: "frb-das-header",
      text: f.title
    });
    // append $element to the <tr>
    $headerHtml.append($element);
  });
  
  // get outerHTML of the <tr>
  return $headerHtml[0].outerHTML;
  // or
  // return $headerHtml.prop("outerHTML");
}

$("body").append(`${buildHeader()}`)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This code iterates over the `headers` and `rows` arrays, creates html and appends the result to `table`:

```js
var headers = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
var rows = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];

$(document).ready(() => {

  $('table')
    .append(
      `<thead><tr>${
        headers.reduce((r, e) => (r += `<th>${e}</th>`) && r, '')
      }</tr></thead>
      <tbody>${
        rows.reduce((r, e) => (r += `<tr>${
          e.reduce((r, e) => (r += `<td>${e}</td>`) && r, '')
        }</tr>`) && r, '')
      }</tbody>`
    )

});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse
}

td,
th {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table></table>
```

Comment: I just get back `null`

Comment: I need to build table headers and rows from an array, I'm trying to build out the html.